# Getting a NullPointerException when trying to iterate over a Queue? (Java)

Tags: java

I'm assuming there's a logic in my error when trying to alter the queue, but I don't know what. I get a `NullPointerException` for the line that reads `if (eventqueue.peek() != null && eventqueue.peek().leavingtime < 61200)`. The queue is not empty, because I can print out elements from it when I try.

The program:

```
QueueLinkedList<Customer> eventqueue = new QueueLinkedList<Customer>();
QueueLinkedList<Customer> customerqueue = new QueueLinkedList<Customer>();
int numberserved = 0, totalidletime = 0, longestbreak = 0, idletime = 0, linelength = 0, longestline = 0;
String[] newarr = new String[8];        

try {
    File file = new File("customersfile.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    reader.readLine();

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        Customer newcust = new Customer();
        if (line.trim().length() > 0) {
            if (line.trim().charAt(0) == 'I') {
                String next;
                next = reader.readLine();
                newcust.id = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(12));
                newcust.arrtime = next.substring(14);
                newcust.setarrtimesecs(newcust.arrtime);
                newcust.setleavingtime(newcust.arrtime);    
                eventqueue.enqueue(newcust);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 

for (int clock = 32400; clock < 86400; clock++) {
    if (eventqueue.peek() != null && eventqueue.peek().leavingtime < 61200) {
        if (eventqueue.peek().arrtimesecs < 32400 || eventqueue.peek().arrtimesecs == clock) {
            if (eventqueue.peek().arrtimesecs == clock) {
                if (customerqueue.peek() == null) 
                    eventqueue.peek().waitingtime = 0;
                else 
                    eventqueue.peek().waitingtime = customerqueue.peek().leavingtime - eventqueue.peek().arrtimesecs;
            }
            if (eventqueue.peek().arrtimesecs < 32400)
                eventqueue.peek().waitingtime = 32400 - eventqueue.peek().arrtimesecs;
            customerqueue.enqueue(eventqueue.dequeue()); 
            linelength++;
            idletime = 0;
            if (longestline != 0) {
                if (linelength > longestline + 1)
                    longestline = linelength - 1;   
            }
        }

        if (customerqueue.peek().leavingtime == clock) {
            numberserved++;
            customerqueue.dequeue();
            linelength--;
            if (customerqueue.peek() == null) 
                idletime = 0;
        }

        while (customerqueue.peek() == null) {
            idletime++;
            totalidletime++;
            if (idletime > longestbreak) 
                longestbreak = idletime;
        }
    }

    else {
        if (eventqueue.peek().arrtimesecs < 61200) {
            if (eventqueue.peek().arrtimesecs == clock) {
                if (customerqueue.peek() == null) 
                    eventqueue.peek().waitingtime = 0;
                else {
                    if (customerqueue.peek().leavingtime >= 61200)
                        eventqueue.peek().waitingtime = 61200 - eventqueue.peek().arrtimesecs;
                }
                customerqueue.enqueue(eventqueue.peek()); 
                linelength++;
                idletime = 0;
                if (longestline != 0) {
                    if (linelength > longestline + 1)
                        longestline = linelength - 1;   
                }
            }

            if (customerqueue.peek().leavingtime == clock) {
                numberserved++;
                customerqueue.dequeue();
                linelength--;
                if (customerqueue.peek() == null) 
                    idletime = 0;
            }

            while (customerqueue.peek() == null) {
                idletime++;
                totalidletime++;
                if (idletime > longestbreak) 
                    longestbreak = idletime;
            }
        }

        else 
            eventqueue.peek().waitingtime = 0;
    }
}
```

My Queue class:

```
Node first, last;

public class Node {
    Customer ele;
    Node next;
}

public QueueLinkedList() {}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return first == null;
}

public QueueLinkedList<Customer> enqueue(Customer ele) {
    Node current = last;
    last = new Node();
    last.ele = ele;
    last.next = null;

    if (current == null) 
        first = last;
    else 
        current.next = last;

    return this;
}

public Customer dequeue() {
    if (isEmpty()) 
        throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException();

    Customer ele = first.ele;
    first = first.next;     
    return ele;
}

public Customer peek() {
    Customer ele = first.ele;
    return ele;
}

public String toString(Customer cust) {
    Node curr = first;
    return "" + curr.ele;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that `leavingtime` is a null wrapper object (ie, it's an Integer, Long, Float or Double with the value null), which would need to be unboxed to compare it to 61200?  Unboxing nulls gives this exception.

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to `peek()` at an empty queue. It would help if you posted the full stack trace.